# Is this a valid keyed lock implementation?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I have been searching for a way to support a keyed locking mechanism that allows any thread to lock or unlock the lock for a given key (so not Guava Striped). Perhaps due to this loosened requirement, all of the examples I have found look much more complicated than the below, and I have been struggling to find a reason why the below is insecure for my use case.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class KeyedLock {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, UUID> locks;

    public KeyedLock(){
        locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public UUID tryLock(String key){
        UUID uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
        UUID res = locks.putIfAbsent(key, uuid);
        if(res){
            return null;
        }
        return uuid;
    }

    public boolean unlock(String key, UUID uuid){
        return locks.remove(key, uuid);
    }
}
```

In order to prevent the accidental unlocking of a lock that someone else holds (because I don't want to restrict it to the same thread), I use a UUID.

Comment: What makes you think this is insecure? One thing to note though: another thread can unlock it using the same uuid when a thread is in its critical section and expecting the lock to remain so. You also need `isLocked` method.

Comment: I don't think it is insecure, but I am trying to make sure. The fact that another thread can unlock it is intentional, and this is the reason why I added UUID, so that there has to be some coordination between the locking and unlocking. When would you use isLocked?

Comment: The API is utterly bizarre: if `tryLock` returns `null`, you have the lock. However, if `tryLock` returns a UUID, you don't.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Good catch, it was meant to be as above.

Answer (score 0):

This method is a source of your future problems:

```
    public UUID tryLock(String key){
        UUID uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
        return locks.putIfAbsent(key, uuid);
    }
```

Thread 1:

```
keyedLock.tryLock("asdf") -> null // UUID(1) registered
```

Thread 2:

```
keyedLock.tryLock("asdf") -> UUID(1) // existing UUID returned
```

I guess you expect the first call return registered UUID, and the second call to reject locking attempt, e.g. in the following way:

```
    @Nullable
    public UUID tryLock(String key){
        UUID uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
        UUID actual = locks.putIfAbsent(key, uuid);
        return actual == null ? uuid : null;
    }
```

I highly recommend to write unit tests first - it will help you understand what do you want/need from this new class.

Comment: Yes, your correction is how I originally intended it.